# Ошибка вложенного Templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, шаблоны

У меня не может найти HTML файлы и выдает эту ошибку

browser page

```
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Типа админ но нет\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testtask\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Типа админ но нет\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testtask\main\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Типа админ но нет\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testtask\blog\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Типа админ но нет\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testtask\account\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Типа админ но нет\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testtask\documentSearcher\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\project\Test\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\project\Test\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\templates\test.html (Source does not exist)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень важно что `templates/templates` я хз почему так показывает ведь я **не** делал *template* в другой *template*.

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

main/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
]
```

main/views.py

```
def index(request):

    context = {'docSearcher': 'docSearcher'}
    return render(request, 'templates/test.html', context)
```

Также есть другие приложения и там все работает нормально с вложенной папкой **templates** в папку с приложениям. (Там только одна папка **templates** в папке с приложением типа *app>templates>index.html*)

Также искал в инете но как загуглить что-то странное типа этого.

Comment: `'templates/test.html'` исправьте на `'test.html'`

Comment: Вау оно выдает другую ошибку, спасибо. кстати я так уже делал и оно не работало, я добалил ```templates/``` потому что думал что оно так будет работать. Оно работает!